# Android Asynchronous task is not calling in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, asynchronous, android-activity, monitor

I have converted an activity to a fragment which consist an asynchronous task to post the data to a server. The asynchronous task is working fine with activity, but it's not working in a fragment. I have kept logs before and after calling the asynchronous task those are coming in an Android monitor, but the logs inside the task are not coming in an Android monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Please share your code.
Try Executing AsyncTask in the onActivityCreated() method of fragment class.